# Pivot Items being left out when grouping

Tags: vba, excel, grouping, pivot-table, pivotitem

I am a VBA noob and humbly need some help. I borrowed a code designed to group specific pivot items. The code works great for the most part but it leaves out 2 pivot items highlighted in the code below that belong (according to the code) to a specific group created. I attached the code and a screen shot. Please help.

Thank you.

```
Dim itm2 As PivotItem
Dim unionrng2 As Range
Dim rLabel2 As Range

For Each itm2 In 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Processor").PivotItems
If (itm2.Name = "Credit Card - Benefit Lifestyle" Or itm2.Name = "Credit 
Card - Benefits Dental" Or itm2.Name = "Credit Card - Benefits Eye" Or 
itm2.Name = "Credit Card - Benefits Lab1 22" Or itm2.Name = "Credit Card - 
Benefits Lab2" Or itm2.Name = "Credit Card - Benefits Save 2" Or itm2.Name = 
"Credit Card - Benefits Save 72" Or itm2.Name = "Credit Card - NMI CH Dental 
2" Or itm2.Name = "Credit Card - NMI CH Eye savings 16" Or itm2.Name = 
"Credit Card - NMI Q1" Or itm2.Name = "Credit Card - NMI Q2" Or itm2.Name 
= "Credit Card - NMI Q3" **<"This one is left out of the group"** Or 
itm2.Name = "Credit Card - NMI Q4") Then
        Set rLabel2 = itm2.LabelRange
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rLabel2 Is Nothing Then
            If unionrng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set unionrng2 = rLabel2
            Else
                Set unionrng2 = Union(unionrng2, rLabel2)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next itm2
unionrng2.Group

Dim itm5 As PivotItem
Dim unionrng5 As Range
Dim rLabel5 As Range

For Each itm5 In 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Processor").PivotItems
    If (itm5.Name = "ACH - AMC Chase 40 (Authorize)" Or itm5.Name = "ACH - 
C&H All (2967)" **<"This one is left out of the group"** Or itm5.Name = "ACH 
- C&H Discount Medical (2992)" Or 
itm5.Name = "ACH - Dental (3342)" Or itm5.Name = "ACH - Lab 1 (3339)" Or 
itm5.Name = "ACH - Lab 2 (3340)" Or itm5.Name = "ACH - Platinum Plus (3341)" 
Or itm5.Name = "ACH - Premier (3343)" Or itm5.Name = "ACH - Vision Benefits 
(3338)") Then
        Set rLabel5 = itm5.LabelRange
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rLabel5 Is Nothing Then
            If unionrng5 Is Nothing Then
                Set unionrng5 = rLabel5
            Else
                Set unionrng5 = Union(unionrng5, rLabel5)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next itm5
unionrng5.Group
```

#### Screen shot of problem

[image: Screen shot of problem]

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, that line of `On Error Resume NExt`, I suggest you to delete it, because it *hides* errors but they still occur. Also, please, be more specific about your problem. What do you mean with *2 items out*? how many items you got? Which ones are left out?

Comment: Thank you! I apologize, pivotitem "Credit Card - NMI Q3" is not grouped with Group2 as it should according to the code, and also pivotitem "ACH - C&H All (2967)" is not grouped with group 5 as it should according to the code.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu Guindon. I need to get better at these sort of things.

Comment: I am still having issues if anyone can help.